# Physical Option Implied Distribuition

Tags: options, black-scholes, research, probability

So I got risk neutral probabilities from stock option prices. How can I then map them to a physical measure?

Comment: You don't need to map them to the physical measure. Please read any of the basic option valuation text books or papers and it should become clearer.

Comment: @MattWolf, *need* is very subjective.

Comment: @Ryogi, care to comment on what you mean with that? If we could always recover the asset price distributions under the general risk measure then why would we use translation tools such as Black Scholes in the first place? If we know the exact price and return distributional properties and therefore know the payoff probabilities of contingent claims then we do not have to bother with risk neutral probabilities. Obviously that is not the case hence my point that we do not "need" the physical measure (other than of course for educational entertainment)

Comment: Sorry, let me be a little more precise. We would still need risk neutral probability measures even if we know the exact distributional properties of the underlying asset because we still do not know the real expected return as a result of unknown utility. But what I see as the biggest problem is that the real distributional properties are unstable, they are dynamic and exhibit very little cointegration, so what is the point of wanting to "recover" them?

Comment: To get an estimate of the market's forecast of returns.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think 'please read any of the basic textbooks...' should be the answer.

Comment: @MattWolf, your first comment refers to option pricing, in which case I agree that one does not need the physical probabilities. At the same time OP did not ask explicitly about pricing. AFAIK this is an active area of research.

Comment: @Ryogi, I appreciate your point, but so is the pursuit of many other subject matters that may, however, never prove futile in actual trading or risk management. My point refers to the fact that some asset price profiles are of such dynamic nature that the derived real-life distribution may be applicable over a short period of time but it may change unpredictably in terms of properties and timing. What is the point to know what the true distribution of the underlying stock price is today if you cannot have confidence that such distribution applies tomorrow or to other stock prices.

Comment: ...but even a broken clock is right twice a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Recovery Theorem](https://www.google.com/#q=recovery+theorem).